# Rename/change entries depending on other MySQL columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with a lot of entries for images that I want to rename. Let's say all the images have the name *Something_X* where X is a number, this is in a column called "name" of my database. There are 2 columns in the database that have the original filesize called "original_width" and "original_height". I want to change all the entries in "name" that it still has the original but it adds the original size to it so that "Something_X" becomes "Something_X_widthxheight", is this possible and how would I do this with PHP my admin in a simple way with preferably a SQL code.

Comment: Please add your code attempt and give us the sample to work with, no one will work with this.

Comment: And add sample data and desired results.

Comment: **image of the database sample:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkhk7bo6zbil7cz/Untitled.png
i have no code sample as i do not know where to start, basiclly i want to update the collumn name. for example in my database that is called "images" i want to uppdate the names, let's for example say that in one collumn for one image that in it's name collumn is called "Tohou_27" has the original "width" and "height" of 1920x1200, i want the name collumn to be updated with this so it becomes "Tohou_27_1920x1200" instead of the original name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE <yourTableName>
SET name = CONCAT(name,'_',original_width,'x',original_height);
```

To update only rows that haven't been updated, you can use the below ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fab8e9/1/0))

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET name = CONCAT(name,'_',original_width,'x',original_height)
WHERE name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%\_',original_width,'x',original_height);
```

Comment: Thanks you very very much! :D Could it be possible to adapt this in someoway to NOT update tables already changed so that if i run it again after i add more wallpapers it wont add it again to the ones already changed? maybe by adding a collumn to check if it's changed or something ?

Comment: @user2406918, check bottom of my answer for query that'll only update rows that haven't been changed to end with _<original_width>x<original_height>.